# when we use "add" in firestore, are we charged both for write and read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when we use "add" in firestore, are we charged both for write and read ?? As a document is sent back as response ... so that if this happens i can use batch with set which doesn't return any document and hence can save money.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `add()` is just billed a write.  It does not send back a document as a response.  You would have to `get()` the written document if you want to see the result of the write.

Comment: sorry I meant "add"

Comment: add behaves the same as set.  They are functionally the same, except that add generates a random ID for the document in the client app.  It doesn't require any reads.